# preventing regex to capture too early

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text which I will be running regex on. I want to match the "selected" option and get its value. In this example Haiti is the selected option.

```
<option value="502">Guatemala (+502)</option><option value="224">Guinea (+224)</option><option value="245">Guinea-Bissau (+245)</option><option value="592">Guyana (+592)</option><option value="509" selected >Haiti (+509)</option><option value="504">Honduras (+504)</option><option value="852">Hong Kong (+852)</option>
```

I tried this regex

```
<option value="(.*?)" selected >
```

which matches

```
224">Guinea (+224)</option><option value="245">Guinea-Bissau (+245)</option><option value="592">Guyana (+592)</option><option value="509
```

I want to match "509" only. Any solutions for this?

Comment: what's ur desired output?

Comment: @طاهر quote: `I want to match "509" only`

Answer (score 2):

You're matching everything from the first `<option value="`, try to not match the quotes instead, i.e. `<option value="([^"]*)" selected >` (meaning anything but double quotes is allowed between the double quotes :) ).